# Margin in chart with x, y data series

Tags: highcharts

In a stacked chart with a data series in the format of [x, y] there is a larger margin on the left and on the right side. I have created the following jsfiddle to with sample data:

http://jsfiddle.net/ymyrA/4/

The code of the chart is as follows:

```
    $(function () {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {"renderTo": "container", "type": "column"},
            colors: ["#2f7ed8", "#0d233a", "#8bbc21", "#910000", "#1aadce", "#492970", "#f28f43", "#77a1e5", "#c42525", "#a6c96a", "#4572A7", "#AA4643", "#89A54E", "#80699B", "#3D96AE", "#DB843D", "#92A8CD", "#A47D7C", "#B5CA92"],
            credits: {"enabled": false},
            plotOptions: {"column": {"stacking": "normal"}},
            series: [
                {"name": "Muster1", "data": [
                    [11, 1],
                    [32, 1]
                ]},
                {"name": "Muster2", "data": [
                    [11, 7],
                    [12, 4],
                    [14, 4],
                    [15, 1],
                    [16, 1],
                    [17, 4],
                    [18, 6],
                    [19, 2],
                    [20, 1],
                    [21, 1],
                    [22, 1],
                    [25, 3],
                    [26, 2],
                    [28, 1],
                    [29, 1],
                    [30, 1]
                ]},
                {"name": "Muster 3", "data": [
                    [11, 2],
                    [13, 2],
                    [15, 1],
                    [16, 3],
                    [18, 5],
                    [19, 11],
                    [20, 8],
                    [21, 1],
                    [23, 3],
                    [24, 12],
                    [27, 3],
                    [28, 4],
                    [30, 3],
                    [31, 3],
                    [33, 3],
                    [34, 3]
                ]}
            ],
            title: {"text": null},
            xAxis: {"title": {"text": "Week"}},
            yAxis: {"title": {"text": "Count"}}
        });
    });
```

I have tried with min and max values, categories, etc. and nothing worked out. How can I adjust the chart to be displayed in full size?

I have updated the code and the jsfiddle with the proper sorting. I was using 3.0 and not 3.05 therefore I had no errors in the console. With the latest version I have to issues remaining. One is the above mentioned large margin at the right and left side and the other one is i am unable (even with tickInterval) to have a tick per calendar week. Based on the above mentioned sample the entire chart should have the range from x=11 to x=34 with a tick on each x.

Comment: what do you mean full size?

Comment: You have Highcharts errors in console - sort your data first, if this won't help upgrade your example with sorted data.

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15

Comment: I added a sort to see if it would solve your problem and it fixes the error, but doesn't solve the issue.  For some reason the series Muster 5 is making things weird.  It looks perfectly normal to me.  If I remove it, the chart obeys min and max.  With it in the chart does not. http://jsfiddle.net/ymyrA/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with calculated `pointRange` for first series - when you have only two points, for x=11 and x=31 it is assumed that minimum interval between points in that series is 20, so Highcharts will try to set interval something about 20. For such cases you need to use `pointRange` for example set it to `1`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ymyrA/5/